# Updated request header via Servlet filter revert back to the original value by the time it reaches the service endpoint in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I want to replace an existing "Authorization" header with a specific Bearer token based on a URL pattern. My filter looks like this:

```
@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
@Slf4j
public class PortalTokenManipulationFilter implements Filter {

    @Autowired
    TokenGeneneratorUtil tokenGeneneratorUtil;

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        Filter.super.init(filterConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        String headerName = "Authorization";
        HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
        if(httpServletRequest.getRequestURI().contains("/specific")){
           String attorneyPortalToken = tokenGeneneratorUtil.generateToken();
           httpServletRequest = new CustomHeaderRequestWrapper(httpServletRequest, HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Bearer " + attorneyPortalToken);
        }
        // Continue the filter chain
        filterChain.doFilter(httpServletRequest, servletResponse);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        Filter.super.destroy();
    }
}
```

And

```
    public class CustomHeaderRequestWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {
    
        private final String headerName;
        private final String newValue;
    
        public CustomHeaderRequestWrapper(HttpServletRequest request, String headerName, String newValue) {
            super(request);
            this.headerName = headerName;
            this.newValue = newValue;
        }
    
        @Override
        public String getHeader(String name) {
            if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(headerName)) {
                return newValue;
            }
            return super.getHeader(name);
        }

}
```

Service endpoint:

```
@RestController
        public class PortalResource {
            public ResponseEntity<?> receiver(@Validated @RequestPart("data") CaseDetail caseDetail, 
            @RequestHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION) String token) throws IOException {
           
            log.info("Token : {} ", token);  // I get the old value of the token
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body("something");
         }
        }
```

When I read the value of the token in my service endpoint (above), I get the old value of the token and not which was updated via Filter.

Answer (score 1):

I implemented the getHeaders() method in CustomHeaderRequestWrapper.java, as shown below. I think this method was called implicitly. Explicitly, implementing this method, besides getHeader(), kept the updated value of my request header (Authorization).

```
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.List;

public class CustomHeaderRequestWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {

    private final String headerName;
    private final String newValue;

    public CustomHeaderRequestWrapper(HttpServletRequest request, String headerName, String newValue) {
        super(request);
        this.headerName = headerName;
        this.newValue = newValue;
    }

    @Override
    public String getHeader(String name) {
        if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(headerName)) {
            return newValue;
        }
        return super.getHeader(name);
    }

    @Override
    public Enumeration<String> getHeaders(String name) {
        List<String> headerValues = Collections.list(super.getHeaders(name));
        int index = 0;
        for (String value : headerValues) {
            if (HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION.equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
                headerValues.set(index, newValue);
            }
            index++;
        }
        return Collections.enumeration(headerValues);
    }
}
```